# MOOC budget dataset

Tags: data-request, finance, mooc

I am looking for a dataset containing MOOC (Massive Open Online Course) budgets, including as many following fields as possible.  The unit of observation is an individual MOOC:

- MOOC title
- platform (edX, Coursera, etc.)
- provider name (Stanford, Microsoft, etc.)
- pay to the teaching staff
- number of students registered to the course
- number of students who completed the course